# Is it valid to predict excess deaths on data used to fit a Poisson regression model?

Tags: poisson-regression, epidemiology

I skimmed through a study: [Excess Death Rates for Republican and Democratic Registered Voters in Florida and Ohio During the COVID-19 Pandemic](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/fullarticle/2807617) that estimates excess death rates of Democrats and Republicans in Florida and Ohio during the COVID-19 pandemic. In short, this is done by fitting a Poisson regression model to actual deaths between 1 January 2018 and 31 December 2019. The model then predicts expected deaths for the whole time period and from this excess deaths can be calculated/estimated. The study has led to figures like this one circulating:

[image]

I wonder if it really makes sense to say, as the text in the diagram does, that

> Before the pandemic deaths were around normal levels for supporters of both parties

? My doubt is that this period is part of the data that was used to fit the Poisson regression model, which makes me think that the model would predict expected deaths close to the actual deaths during this period, regardless of what the actual deaths were. In order to say that the deaths were around normal for this period 2018-2020, wouldn't one have to fit a model to the time period before 2018 and compare its predictions to the actual deaths 2018-2020?

Comment: I agree, unless the people who made the figure were drawing on additional information about typical death rates pre-2018.

Comment: I interpreted that line as a restatement of "Before the pandemic, the curves were roughly horizontal for both parties and didn't fluctuate much from week to week", not a statement about fit.

Comment: there is no need to appeal to a model to answer the question, and indeed the figure doesn't: prior to the pandemic, the difference between the red and blue lines is small and not consistently positive or negative. Afterwards, the difference seems to grow slightly and the red line is consistently above the blue one. If you are worried about some particular aspect of their model, it would be helpful for us if you reproduced the relevant math here for us. I agree that their phrasing "around normal" is somewhat of a tautology; "about equal" would have been better phrasing.